# Can't download the library struct in python 2.7

Tags: python

Can you please help me, I can't install the package "struct" in python 2.7.

**command** : python -m pip install struct

**python version**: 2.7.16

**Error message**: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement struct (from versions:none)
No matching distribution found for struct

So have you got any ideas on fixing that guys?

Comment: struct is a built-in library. It does not need to be installed.

Comment: note: everything listed here https://docs.python.org/2/library/ is built-in (also, if possible move to Python 3!)